# Return nil from generic func constrained to interface?

Tags: go, generics

I'm about to migrate existing code to use go generics. This very basic example shows the problem:

```golang
// Just an interface
type Object interface {
    Test() error
}

// A func returning an interface can return `nil`
func Get() Object {
    return nil 
}

// Why I can't return `nil` from a generic func constrained to `interface Object`?
func GetG[T Object]() T {
    return nil // ./prog.go:15:9: cannot use nil as T value in return statement
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/3WTg1aYDzCA

If `func Get`, which returns `interface Object` is allowed to return `nil`, why is the generic version `func GetG` where T is constrained to `Object` not allowed to do so?

Can anyone tell me more about the behaviour or the rational behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type parameter **is not** its constraint.

1. the constraint only restricts the concrete types that can be used to instantiate that type parameter and may determine what operations that type parameter supports
2. the type parameter exists only at compile time. At run time the code operates with whatever concrete type argument was supplied to the function.
3. `nil` may not be assignable to the concrete type argument

Intuitively, let's say I implement your interface with a defined integer type:

```
type Foo int8
func (Foo) Test() error { return nil }
```

Does `Foo` satisfy the constraint `Object`? Yes, it implements the method. Can I instantiate `GetG` with `Foo`? Yes, it satisfies the constraint. Can I assign `nil` to `Foo`? [No, I can't](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value):

> When storage is allocated for a variable, [...] the variable or value is given a default value. [...] `nil` for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

Therefore, you can't always return `nil` if the return type is a type parameter. You may return `nil` in other circumstances:

- if the return type is a pointer to a type parameter, but that's not `T`, it's `*T`.

```
func GetG[T Object]() *T {
    return nil // ok
}
```

- if you can assign `nil` to all types in the type parameter's type set — identified by its constraint:

```
// type set comprises only *int and *string
func GetG[T *int | *string]() T {
    return nil // ok
}
```

The case above is mentioned by the language spec in [Assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value `x` of type `V` is assignable to a variable of type `T` [...] if
>
> [...]
>
> - x is the predeclared identifier `nil`, T is a type parameter, and x is assignable to each type in T's type set.

With a basic interface (methods only) as a constraint, this condition doesn't hold for the reason explained above: you can satisfy it with types which `nil` isn't assignable to.

Otherwise what you can do is to return `T`'s zero value, which you can do in several different ways, the most straightforward one is:

```
func GetG[T Object]() T {
    var zero T
    return zero
}
```